# Parsing soap response using Python etree returning empty dictionary

Tags: python, soap

I've tried to parse sessionId field from the below xml/soap response like below, but all child attribute dictionaries are empty:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom

url="http://172.16.46.85:8080/CAI3G1.2/services/CAI3G1.2"

headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}

body = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"             xmlns:cai3="http://schemas.ericsson.com/cai3g1.2/">
    <soapenv:Body>
            <cai3:Login>
                    <cai3:userId>admin</cai3:userId>
                    <cai3:pwd>admin</cai3:pwd>
            </cai3:Login>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""

response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)

print 'content : ' + str(response.content)
print '##################################################'
print 'text : ' + str(response.text)
print '##################################################'

root = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)

for child in root.iter('*'):
    print 'child tag : ' + child.tag
    print 'child attrib : ' + str(child.attrib)

print '##################################################'

for child in root:
    print child.tag, child.attrib

print '##################################################'
```

below is the execution result, I'm not seeking any solution using re, i know it can be done using re library, i want to know how it could be achieved using etree (if it can be done) :

```
[root@web soap_python]# ./getSessionID_PG.py
content : <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:LoginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.ericsson.com/cai3g1.2/"><ns2:sessionId>c70f2a0f7e7d4c5084bea857715e2d10</ns2:sessionId><ns2:baseSequenceId>306324732</ns2:baseSequenceId></ns2:LoginResponse></S:Body></S:Envelope>
##################################################
text : <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:LoginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.ericsson.com/cai3g1.2/"><ns2:sessionId>c70f2a0f7e7d4c5084bea857715e2d10</ns2:sessionId><ns2:baseSequenceId>306324732</ns2:baseSequenceId></ns2:LoginResponse></S:Body>    </S:Envelope>
##################################################
child tag : {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope
child attrib : {}
child tag : {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body
child attrib : {}
child tag : {http://schemas.ericsson.com/cai3g1.2/}LoginResponse
child attrib : {}
child tag : {http://schemas.ericsson.com/cai3g1.2/}sessionId
child attrib : {}
child tag : {http://schemas.ericsson.com/cai3g1.2/}baseSequenceId
child attrib : {}
##################################################
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body {}
##################################################
[root@web soap_python]
```

Answer (score 1):

All the tags have no attribute except for the `xmlns`, which ElemenTree seems to exclude because is some "well known" information. If you need the `sessionId` tag, you should already know that it is part of the http://schemas.ericsson.com/cai3g1.2/ namespace.

With `Element.find()` you can use XPath expressions to search for a specific tag. Ex:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
s = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:LoginResponse xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.ericsson.com/cai3g1.2/"><ns2:sessionId>c70f2a0f7e7d4c5084bea857715e2d10</ns2:sessionId><ns2:baseSequenceId>306324732</ns2:baseSequenceId></ns2:LoginResponse></S:Body>    </S:Envelope>'''
root = ElementTree.fromstring(s)
ns = {'cai3g1.2': 'http://schemas.ericsson.com/cai3g1.2/'}
root.find('.//cai3g1.2:sessionId', ns).text
'c70f2a0f7e7d4c5084bea857715e2d10'
root.find('.//cai3g1.2:baseSequenceId', ns).text
'306324732'
```

Comment: it's working like this, but i'm not sure that i understand how it's working here. do you have any reference for this topic that could be helpful since i'm still new in python and soap/xml parsing.